# what's the python way to use translate in a way that works for str and unicode?

Tags: python, string, unicode, unicode-string

i have a function that cleans an str of specific characters:

```
def _clean_name(name):
    return name.translate(None, "\n ").replace('.', '_')
```

now this function must support unicode as well, so i ended up with this version:

```
def _clean_name(name):
    if type(name) is unicode:
        return name.translate({ord('\n'): None, ord(' '): None, ord('.'): ord('_')})
    else:
        return name.translate(None, "\n ").replace('.', '_')
```

but that doesn't feel too pythonic to me. anyone has a nicer solution?

Comment: The real pythonic solution is "Use Python 3" (after all it was decided that having 2 differently behaving types for text was not Pythonic).

Comment: If someone derived from class `unicode`, your check would fail, use `isinstance()` instead. That said, upgrading to Python 3 is a good advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more an *hackish* way of doing than a Pythonic one -- but one advantage is that it will remove code duplication and should probably work on subclasses of unicode (you definitively need to check that if needed!).

So, taking benefit that the type object is callable and that both unicode and str implements the `join` operation:

```
def _clean_name(name):
    return type(name)().join(
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
#           build an empty str or unicode object
        [{'.': '_', '\n':'', ' ':''}.get(c,c) for c in name]
    )
```

Comment: Wouldn't `name[0:0]` also return an empty stringish of the same type? Feels better to me than looking at the `type`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Not necessarily in case of sub-typing (there was a reference to that in a (deleted) comment this morning). Or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `translate` has a different syntax for byte strings and Unicode strings, even in Python 3.  There is a `maketrans` method to help build translation tables, but only Python 3 has a version for Unicode.  I would write a version for Python 2.x, but otherwise use a version of your method to call the right version of `translate`:

```
import string

def unicode_maketrans(s,t,d=None):
    '''Generate a translation dictionary.
       Map ordinals in s to ordinals in t.
       Map ordinals in d to None.
    '''
    D = dict(zip(map(ord,s),map(ord,t)))
    if d:
        D.update({ord(c):None for c in d})
    return D

str_table = string.maketrans('.','_')
str_del = '\n '
uni_table = unicode_maketrans(u'.',u'_',u'\n ')

def clean_name(name):
    if isinstance(name,unicode):
        return name.translate(uni_table)
    else:
        return name.translate(str_table,str_del)

print repr(clean_name('this is.a test\n'))
print repr(clean_name(u'this is.a test\n'))
```

Output:

```
'thisis_atest'
u'thisis_atest'
```

Comment: This is for Python 2 or I wouldn't have had to write `unicode_maketrans` :)

Comment: sorry - my bad - for some reason I read the Q as "how do I make a string translate method that works in 2/3" - not as "unicode/str" - mea culpa :p (never mind the fact the title says exactly that... *sighs* - guess there's reading between the lines too much :p)

Answer (score 0):

`_clean_name` is *protected*, so it's file/class-local. I'd either assume that the class works on `unicode` strings, or do the conversion on cleaning:

```
def _clean_name(name):
    if isinstance(name, str):
        name = unicode(str)
    return name.translate({ord('\n'): None, ord(' '): None, ord('.'): ord('_')})
```

Yes, people like to say Python's duck-typed, but inside code you own, it's incredibly nice to *know* that `name` is a unicode string, not a byte string. Python 3 even acknowledged that `type('foo') == str` was a mistake and you want unicode string literals 99% of the time, but so much legacy code out there uses byte strings that you usually have to support them.